# how to use -NoDefaultExcludes when creating a nuget package

Tags: nuget, travis-ci

I have a travis build script In that script it packs a nuget package

```
dotnet pack src/Google.Analytics.SDK.Core --configuration $BUILD_CONFIGURATION --no-restore --no-build --output $NUPKG_DIR /p:NuspecFile=$NUSPEC_PATH
```

the $NUSPEC_PATH is a `.nuspec` file.

I am getting the following warning in my build.

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.301/Sdks/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/build/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(198,5):
>   warning NU5119: File
>   '/home/travis/build/LindaLawton/google-analytics-dotnet-sdk/deploy/.nuspec'
>   was not added to the package. Files and folders starting with '.' or
>   ending with '.nupkg' are excluded by default. To include this file,
>   use -NoDefaultExcludes from the commandline
>   [/home/travis/build/LindaLawton/google-analytics-dotnet-sdk/src/Google.Analytics.SDK.Core/Google.Analytics.SDK.Core.csproj]
>   Successfully created package
>   '/home/travis/build/LindaLawton/google-analytics-dotnet-sdk/NuPkg/Daimto.Google.Analytics.Tracker.SDK.1.0.0-beta.nupkg'.

I am having trouble figureing out where it wants me to add this `-NoDefaultExcludes`

- I tried adding it as its own command and that failed.
- I tried adding it to the dotnet pack and that didnt work either
- I have tried renaming the file to .xml which doesnt work either.

Answer (score 23):

Add the tag **NoDefaultExcludes** to **PropertyGroup** of the project you are targeting in pack command.
Something like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <PackageType>Template</PackageType>
        ...
        <NoDefaultExcludes>true</NoDefaultExcludes>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a property called NoPackageAnalysis to true in your csproj file or from the command line pass /p:NoPackageAnalysis=true